# Hi How to add picture from mobile to pc?

Tags: image

Hi How to add picture from mobile to pc? Hi How to add picture from mobile to pc?

Comment: The micron/pixel ratio depends on the image scale, that means on the zoom level of your microscope. Why your mosaic changes that I do not know, but probably has to do with the software you're using to do that. You should describe the steps you take and the software/hardware you use in much more detail.

Comment: Again: Using what software? What brand/type of microscope are you using? The question you ask is very specific to your problem, and without detailed information it will be very unlikely that somebody is able to answer it.

Comment: I guess so yes, but I cannot answer. I know neither.